# I have one category. How print all articles of subcategories without additional gems? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my code.
I take testing category one -- nevermind please.

```
  // Controller
  @categories = Category.find(1).subcategories # Works exellent
  @articles = []
  @categories.each do |category|
     @articles[category.id] = category.articles
  end
```

---

```
  // View
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <h2><%= category.title %></h2>
      <ul>
          <% @articles[category.id].each do |article| %>
             <li><a href="<%= article.slug %>"><%= article.title %></a></li>
          <% end %>
      </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my output (where 'vel', 'in', 'sit' -- subcategories names):

```
vel
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>]
in
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>]
sit
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>, #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>]
```

---

I have correct work associations:

Catogory:

```
has_many :articles
has_many :subcategories
has_one :parent
```

Article

```
belongs_to :category
```

---

I read lot of documentation and find some helpful gems (awesome_nested_set, ancestry) but wanna know how do it without additional gems

Comment: `@articles` is an array, you need a hash: `@articles = {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it much cleaner:

```
# Controller
@categories = Category.find(1).subcategories.includes(:articles)

# View
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <h2><%= category.title %></h2>
  <ul>
    <% category.articles.each do |article| %>
      <%= link_to article.title, article.slug %>   # Do you really use slug for url? 
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think its work, but I see only subcategory names =( tryed add `belongs_to :category, -> { includes :subcategory }` to Article model... still does not work.

Comment: @goodniceweb - That's because you have no articles associated with those categories: `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` - note empty array at the end.

Comment: thank you very much for your patience. Yes, life is pain: I migrate to new OS and forget that `db:populate` random. What about `slug`: its dangerous? I just use FriendlyId.

Comment: @goodniceweb - Does it return a real-life url? It is hard to say without seeing your slug_candidates method. Do you have other method which would state clearly what it is (like `url` or sth?) Also using url for friendly_id is slightly weird, the whole purpose of this gem is to simplify urls, passing some encoded url in url usually doesn't look pretty.

Comment: I have one nesting level most all pages. But I understand what you keep in mind. Yes, its good idea: I went to write `url` method)